# Is for( auto it : vect ) required to iterate in vect order?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, vector, iterator

Can I rely on the following loop to iterate in order:

```
vector<A> a;
for( auto i : a )
{
    // Does i loop from the first to the last element in a, or i can come in any order?
}
```

Comment: Yes, by the nature of iterators

Comment: For a vector, you can. It's a proper sequence. Other containers may not guarantee any particular order.